# GraphQL query operations limit on URL length

Tags: url, graphql, limit

I have started using GraphQL on a new project and am concerned with the length of the URL that gets generated when sending the query.  I mean, wouldn't we ultimately hit the limit of the url length when issuing GraphQL queries.  Are there workarounds to this?

Comment: Yeah, that could certainly happen in some cases, here is a related issue on this: https://github.com/graphql/graphiql/issues/590

Answer (score 2):

GraphQL requests are normally sent as POST requests with the `application/json` Content Type.  The body of the request is a JSON object that consists of three properties -- `query`, `variables` and `operationName`. Here, `query` is the entire GraphQL [document](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/#sec-Language.Document) being sent from the client to the server, regardless of the actual operation type. So your request might look something like:

As outlined [here](https://graphql.github.io/learn/serving-over-http/), GraphQL server implementations normally also support GET requests, as well as POST requests that include the `application/graphql` type. Both of these other two methods are less flexible than the former, though:

- GET requests not only potentially face issues with URL length limits, but some (most?) server implementations limit these requests to `query` operations only -- in other words, often [you cannot send mutations using GET](https://github.com/graphql/express-graphql/issues/17).
- POST requests that use an `application/graphql` Content Type treat the whole request body as the document, which means they don't provide a way to send variables or specify which operation in the document should be ran.

You should probably be using POST requests with `application/json` Content Type, unless you have some unique client limitation that prevents you from doing so.

Comment: Wouldn't fundamentally sending a GET request in a POST cause other issues.  For example automatically re-sending GET requests.  Surely there must be a better solution for this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "sending a GET request in a POST". You either send it as a GET request or as a POST. The point of the answer was that you should avoid using GET requests in GraphQL and stick with POST. Sorry if that wasn't clear enough.

Comment: Yup I understood that you should send the graphql queries in POST, but what I'm fundamentally trying to get at is, this is a GET request and (requesting data) and POST is usually for updating, wouldn't this cause other problems.

Comment: No. GraphQL makes using different request methods like PATCH, DELETE, GET, etc. unnecessary. All requests are POST requests. You differentiate between fetching and mutating data through the document you pass in the request body - specifically the operation type (query vs mutation)

Comment: Actually I was referring more around surrounding libraries and not graphql itself.  For example some of the http libraries tend to fire GET requests multiple times if the first request fails and not necessarily POST requests since it could potentially be modifying data twice.

Comment: Ah, ok I see what you're getting at. I can't really speak to that since I don't think I've ran into that issue. I don't know if I've used any client libraries that have such granular behavior by default. So I guess it could be an issue if you're trying to integrate with some existing client lib that does that, though I expect in most cases, you would be using a GraphQL client lib like Apollo anyway.